# How to read the content of CI CD Variable of type File into my docker container run on pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab variable stored in a file format

When I tried to access the file using my python code

like

```
variable Key :  KEY_FILE value: 'hsdasds'
```

in my python code `pack.py`

```
with open($KEY_FILE) as f:
    f.read()
```

I get File not found error but its showing the file path when I did

```
before_script -echo ' $KEY_FILE'
```

My query is how can I read the content(I will read it in docker container as my python code will run in a docker container) of the file define in variable ..

```
docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/mnt python 'executors/pack.py' "$KEY_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to firstly copy the file to your current working directory

```
cp $KEY_FILE .
```

And then run

```
docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/mnt python 'executors/pack.py' "/mnt/KEY_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by below ways

1. First in gitlab-,ci.yml

   ```
   cp ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/KEY_FILE /tmp/gitkey
   ```

2.in Dockerfile

```
    ADD /tmp/gitkey
```

3. Now in code

   ```
   with open("/tmp/gitkey") as f:
     f.read()
   ```